# How does this bash function for removing all but some files work?

Tags: bash

I've found the following script on [commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/) (the example is not online anymore):

```
rmbut() { 
    local x=("$@")
    IFS=, rm -rf *[!"${x[*]}"] 
}
```

It deletes all files and directories but the ones named on the command line.

Could you explain the following:

- What is happening on the first line? `$@` means all arguments, but why is it put inside parentheses?
- I've read about `IFS` but never actually used it, what is its usage here?
- What is achieved with `*[!"${x[*]}"]`? I can't understand how to split it into something I know.

Comment: Are you sure those are parentheses () on "local x.." line or are they braces {} or brackets [].  It makes a difference.  Also, from the looks of the function, it's simply removing all files except any that have the basename(s) specified by the parameters to the function.

Comment: Yes, the parentheses are correct. That is the purpose of the function, that is clear, I would like to know why ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`local x=("$@")` creates an array which is a copy of all the arguments (`$@` is itself an array).

`IFS=,` sets the internal field separator to a comma.

`IFS=, rm -rf *[!"${x[*]}"]` says to remove all files that do not end in any character passed as arguments. Since `*` is used as the index to the array and the variable is quoted it is expanded to a single string and the spaces that would normally separate the elements of the array are replaced by the contents of `IFS` (a comma in this case).

```
rmbut a b c
```

resolves to `rm -rf *[!a,b,c]` which would also not remove files that end in a comma.

I ***think*** the function could be simplified to:

```
rmbut() { 
    IFS= rm -rf *[!"$*"] 
}
```

but its behavior would be subtly different. This version sets `IFS` to null so the example above would resolve to `rm -rf *[!abc]` which *would* remove files that end in a comma (a comma would have to be passed explicitly as an argument to preserve such files). However, that behavior could be returned by setting `IFS=,` (it's simply not necessary to copy the array).

Answer (score 3):

# create an array x, containing arguments to the function
`local x=("$@")`

# unset the IFS variable. This make double quoted arrays expand to single words w/o separators
`IFS=`

# remove files matching a pattern, i.e. not ending with a character from the array x
`rm -rf *[!"${x[*]}"]`

Comment: @eugene y: You wrote `IFS=` but the original is `IFS=,` did you make a typo or the comma is there to separate `IFS` from the other content of the line?

Comment: @eugene y: Are you sure? I've just tried it right now, copy pasted from the commandlinefu.com and it works...

Comment: @Alberto: `touch abc bcd cde; rmbut bcd  # removes "cde" only`

Comment: @eugene y: With that input it does not work, you are right, neither with nor without the `,` after `IFS`, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I read that behavior as correct. "Remove the files *but* the ones that end in "b" or "c" or "d". Since `abc` ends in "c" it is not removed.

Comment: @Dennis: On the page that the OP has linked it states: "Remove all but $1, $2, $3, ..., $n". Therefore it's not correct.

Comment: The poster on commandlinefu is confused. So yes, you are correct, the function is incorrect. Sorry, I did not look at the linked page before. However, `IFS=,` is not the source of the problem.